# WP theme setting 2 images in the header via custom-header

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP template that set the header image using the following in the functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );
        $defaults = array(
            'default-image'          => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/100.png',
            'width'                  => 1100,
            'height'                 => 500,
        );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $defaults );
```

I want to be able to set 2 images in the header and update these via the admin appearance->header menu, is this possible? Any reference to documentation on this would help as I couldn't find any.

If I add the following, both are under one section, is there anyway to split them:

```
function example_customizer( $wp_customize ) {

$wp_customize->add_section(
        'example_section_one',
        array(
            'title' => 'Example Settings',
            'description' => 'This is a settings section.',
            'priority' => 35,
        )
);

$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'copyright_textbox',
    array(
        'default' => 'Default copyright text',
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    'copyright_textbox',
    array(
        'label' => 'Copyright text',
        'section' => 'example_section_one',
        'type' => 'text',
    )
);

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'example_customizer' );





function example_customizer1( $wp_customize ) {


    $wp_customize->add_section(
        'example_section_img',
        array(
            'title' => 'Example img',
            'description' => 'This is a settings img.',
            'priority' => 36,
        )
    );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'img-upload' );

$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'img-upload',
        array(
            'label' => 'Image Upload',
            'section' => 'example_section_one',
            'settings' => 'img-upload'
        )
    )
);


}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'example_customizer1' );
```

Comment: You can achieve this using Theme customizer of wordpress 
Follow this link it will give full details of theme customize http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-theme-customizer/

Comment: @php-weblineindia Thank you, i can get this section added. How do I now hook this into the index.php, do you know what the reference of the image would be? I have tried <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'example_customizer'); ?> example_customizer is name of function.

Comment: You can Add $YourVarriableName = get_theme_mod(''example_customize"); and echo this variable whenever you want .

Comment: @PHP Weblineindia - Thank you for your help, one last question, is there anyway to have these as individual option is the customizer? I have added the code above but both are shown in the same drop down?

Comment: Yes you can create individual section for it  follow the given links all steps for more details : http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-theme-customizer